# updating a line in cakephp

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I'm trying to create a simple request/accept function. A user adds a person - both users usernames are added to the table along with an autogenerated id. Now when the other user checks their requests they click approve and add an expiry date to the the record. Currently whats happening is that when a user clicks accept and sets an expiry date it creates a new record in the Relationship table.

the structure of my relationship table is

```
id
partyone
partytwo
active
expirydate
```

public function add(){

```
        if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->Relationship->create();
        if ($this->Relationship->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $id=$this->Relationship->id;
            $this->Session->setFlash('The relationship has been saved'); 

        }
        else { $this->Session->setFlash('The relationship could not be saved. Please, try again.'); }
        }

      }



        public function approve(){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Relationship->id;
            $this->Relationship->getLastInsertID();
            $this->Relationship->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('The information has been saved');}
            else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('The information couldnt be saved');}


        }


    }
```

here is my approve view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Relationship', array('action'=>'approve'));
echo $this->Form->input('expirydate',array('label'=>'Expiry Date: ', 'class' => 'dateclass')); 
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

?>
```

here is my add view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Relationship', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('partyone',array('label'=>'Enter your username: '));
echo $this->Form->input('partytwo',array('label'=>'Username of user: '));
echo "<br />";
echo $this->Form->end('Click here to add relationship');

?>
```

how can i code this so it updates and not creates a new line with expiry date, please help I am losing my mind over this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not making anysense. Is this a typo :

```
        $this->Relationship->id;
        $this->Relationship->getLastInsertID();
```

It should obviously read :

```
        $this->Relationship->id = $this->Relationship->getLastInsertID();
```

Comment: This won't work as `getLastInsertID()` will return null because nothing has been inserted yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a hidden field to your "approve" view with the id of the relationship you are going to edit. If the submitted data contains an id, the `save()` method will update the specified record instead of creating a new one.

You can find an example in the cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information, but the basic idea is:

On your `approve` view you need to have a field that stores the `id` of the `relationship` to be approved.

You can store the `ID` as a param for the `approve` method, or as a hidden field.

```
function approve($id=null) {
    /*Form action = Relationship/Approve/ID*/
    $this->Relationship->id = $id;
    /*or - hidden field/an input*/
    $this->Relationship->id = $this->request->data['Relationship']['id'];
    $this->Relationship->save($this->request->data);
}
```

providing `id` is set before you save, Cake will update, instead of adding.

Comment: its throwing Undefined index: Relationship with the $this->request->data['Relationship']['id'];

it doesnt like whats in the square brackets. I thought you were supposed to put fields in the table there